# What are families of graphs called which we can "grow" by induction?

Tags: graph-theory, induction, terminology

Consider the following proof by induction:

> **Theorem.** All trees are $2$-colorable.
>
> **Proof.** We induct on $n$, the number of vertices in the tree. When $n=1$, we may give the only vertex any color we like.
>
> Assume that all $n$-vertex trees are $2$-colorable. To prove this for $(n+1)$-vertex trees, take an $n$-vertex tree $T$, $2$-color it, and then add an $(n+1)^{\text{th}}$ vertex $v$ connected by an edge to any vertex of $T$. The resulting tree $T+v$ can be $2$-colored by giving $v$ the opposite color of the vertex we just connected it to.
>
> By induction, the theorem holds for all $n$.

This is not a very good proof, but it can be made to work by clarifying an unstated assumption: any $(n+1$)-vertex tree can be obtained by adding on to an $n$-vertex tree. (I've seen a textbook call this the "Tree Growing Procedure", possibly only for the sake of the pun.)

The corresponding assumption is *not* true for all kinds of graphs, and assuming it's always true leads us to such classic mistakes as:

> **Theorem.** All planar graphs are $4$-colorable.
>
> **Nonproof.** It suffices to color all *maximal* (triangulated) planar graphs, because we can always add edges to a planar graph to triangulate it, and a proper coloring of the triangulation is also a proper coloring of the original graph.
>
> We prove this by induction on $n$. For $n \le 4$, a $4$-coloring exists because we may give each vertex its own color.
>
> Assume that all $n$-vertex planar triangulations are $4$-colorable. To prove this for $(n+1)$-vertex planar triangulations, take an $n$-vertex one and add another vertex to it, drawing all possible edges.
>
> The new vertex was added to the middle of a (triangular) face, so it is connected to three vertices of that triangle. The $n$-vertex graph had a $4$-coloring by the inductive hypothesis, which we may extend to a coloring of the new graph by giving the new vertex a color different from any of the three colors use for those vertices.
>
> By induction, the theorem holds for all $n$.

(I'm possibly not making the argument very *convincing*, because I know it's wrong - but variants of this mistake are very common among students first learning graph theory.)

My question: is there a word for the families of graphs (or of combinatorial objects in general; this issue isn't limited to graph theory) for which a "Growing Procedure" exists, and this type of argument works? Is there a theory of when "Growing Procedures" exist?

Answer (score 6):

I have often heard a graph property called *hereditary* when the property is closed under taking arbitrary induced subgraphs. However, this is somewhat stronger than the property you seem to be looking for: in a hereditary graph class, you can delete *any* vertex (or any subset of vertices) and get another graph with the desired property, while you just want there to be *some* vertex whose deletion yields a graph with the desired property. In particular, the property of being a tree is not hereditary, but the property of being a forest (disjoint union of trees) is hereditary, and it's possible to use this fact to prove that forests are 2-colorable in the same way you outlined in your question.

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice connection to make and if I end up making up a name of these graph properties maybe I'll call them "weakly hereditary" or something. But it'd be better to find out that someone else has already made up a name and then gone on to say lots of clever things about such graph properties.

Comment: Another property that's close to what you want is the concept of an "elimination ordering". Chordal graphs are characterized by having a *simplicial* elimination ordering: an ordering v_1, ..., v_n such that, when we delete the vertices in the specified order, each vertex has a clique for its neighborhood when it is deleted. People have also looked at other kinds of "elimination orderings", but I've usually seen them defined in terms of the neighborhood of $v$ when $v$ is deleted, not in terms of the overall structure of the graph when $v$ is deleted.

Comment: see, for example: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2014.12.014

Comment: Well, I was hoping to find more specific references, but it looks like nobody knows anything more than you do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

There is a class of stronger properties than you ask for, however it is applicable to your example. This class is called [connected-hereditary properties](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022000008000512/1-s2.0-S0022000008000512-main.pdf?_tid=3007d334-2620-11e7-a31a-00000aacb360&acdnat=1492730714_f94739a23f2a392c5c1e06732b7fa37c), i. e. graph properties that are closed with respect to connected induced subgraphs. Particularly, being a tree is a connected-hereditary property.

Comment: Thank you; I guess this is the most general term so far. A couple of natural examples of "growable" properties that show it's still too specific: being an Apollonian network; having average degree less than $k$ for any fixed $k$.